# Newtonsoft direct json property name mapping

Tags: c#, json.net

I have data classes with long propertynames. The frontend application is developed to accept those propertynames. I'm currently not able to change backend and frontend since there are way to many classes. Due to versioning and polymorphism of my models I decided to save them in the db as jsons ( using Postgres Jsonb capabilities ).

The propertynames are taking up so much unnecessary space in the db and I want to prevent that. So I thought to use the JsonProperty attribute from newtonsoft to give them shorter names in the backend and only store them in the "shortend" version. But now I need to convert them from shortend to regular and vise versa depending on the direction the data is going (frontend -> backend, backend -> frontend).

How can I achieve this without serializing and deserializing everytime into the class ?

Regards !

Comment: Create 2 models and map between them and be done with it. Also this should all likely be refractored

Comment: Why wouldn't you use serialisation? It's quite efficient nowadays. 
As another solution you could do string replacements within the json - but you would not notice errors immediately with such approach